# Windows Forms radio button click event is getting on start up

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I have eight radio buttons on a user control. Each of them has or will have their own click handler. The first one has its click handler called when the user control is added to the main window. Is this normal behavior for Windows Forms (I am relatively new to .NET from a Java background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect is likely the result of the default control selection rather than the control being added to the form.  When the form finishes loading, one of the controls on the form will become the active control/have focus.  If that control is a radio button, the button becomes checked, which will fire events like `Click` and `CheckChanged` (unless the radio button `Checked` property was already set to true).  Depending on the `Checked` property value of the other buttons, you may see their `CheckChanged` events fire as well.

To test this out yourself, change the `TabIndex` property value in the designer so that some other control on the form will have the lowest index.  This will make that control have focus on startup instead of the radio button(s).  When this happens, you should not see the `Click` event being fired when the form is loaded.

Comment: For the record this behavior also occurs when a radio button is nested inside a user control and that control is default in a form.